# Writing Data to multiple sheets of an excel file using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, export

Need to write data to multiple sheets of a excel file using Angular JS. 
Any inputs would be valuable.

Comment: You cannot write files using AngularJS

Comment: is it possible using any other libraries like FileSaver.js or Alasql.js ??

Comment: Using FileSaver, IMK,  yes in a way, create a file using `new File()` or `new Blob()` then save it(download) using fileSaver, but in no way, you will be able to modify the existing files. Don't know about Alasql.js, looks like in-memory DB, so again no!